# Global/local optima for this function

Tags: functions, optimization

I have the following function

$f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{x_1}{x_2+p} + \frac{x_2}{x_1+p}$

where $x_1$ and $x_2$ $\in$ $[0,1]$ and $p > 0$ is a constant

I want to find global/local maxima for this. Please suggest some good methods. I already looked at stochastic ones (like PSO etc) but I am looking for other ways in which I can simplify my function.

Comment: can $p > 0$ ?.......

Comment: A necessary condition for f assumes a maximum or local minimum is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = 0$.

Comment: @8pir yes, i updated the question

Comment: Use the second partial test

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The function is convex in each of the variables, hence the extreme values occur at the end points of the interval. I hope that helps.

Comment: How can you say it is convex in each variable? Can you please give some mathematical proof?

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_i} = \dfrac{2x_j}{(x_i+p)^3} > 0$